# Swift array cannot be downcast to array of derived

Tags: core-data, swift, xcode6

I am using Core Data in Swift and am having trouble storing the array returned from a fetch request. I have two entities in my data model: Task and Homework. Homework's parent entity is Task. I auto generated the classes for the two entities:

Task.swift

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

class Task: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var name: String
    @NSManaged var due: NSDate
    @NSManaged var subject: Subject

}
```

Homework.swift

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

class Homework: Task {
}
```

In my view controller, in view did load, I have the following code.

```
var error: NSError? = nil
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest()
let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Task", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext)
fetchRequest.entity = entity
tasks = managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: &error) as [Task]
```

Earlier in the view controller, I initialized tasks:

```
var tasks : [Task] = []
```

However, when I run the the application, I get the following runtime error at the line where I assign the array to tasks: `fatal error: array cannot be downcast to array of derived`

If I replace the assignment line with `var temp = managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: &error) as [NSManagedObject]`, the error does not occur, but I need to save it as an array of Tasks in order to be able to use the custom classes that I generated. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Compare "Implementing Core Data Managed Object Subclasses" in https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/WritingSwiftClassesWithObjective-CBehavior.html.

Answer (score 2):

You have to add the module or app name to the class name in the model editor:

```
MyApp.Task
```

This has to be done *after* you generate the class file, otherwise that part fails. I consider this a bug in the current beta, and have raised it as such.

My previous answer stated to use the @objc decorator, which also works, but the above solution is documented in the swift / cocoa reference.

Comment: According to https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/WritingSwiftClassesWithObjective-CBehavior.html, the proper solution is to include the module/app name in the entities class (and then it works without `@objc(Task)`, at least in my test). Of course Xcode should to that when auto-creating the managed object subclasses.

Comment: @MartinR oh, interesting. Is that new in the documentation or have I just been missing it all this time? Would be nice for it to point to it from the NSManagedObject class reference...

Comment: I don't know, but Ben's answer to the duplicate question is from June 11, so I *assume* that it is already documented for a while.

Comment: OK thanks. I've updated my bug report to be a documentation fix and for the module name to be added to the class by the generator.

Answer (score 1):

According to the XCode Release Notes for Beta 4 the downcast should work now:

> Objects of a class type, such as NSObject or NSArray, can now be downcast to bridged Swift
>   types.

(Haven't tried that though)

However, you can cast the objects in your tasks array when you need them:

```
tasks = managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: &error)  // array of NSManagedObjects

for obj in tasks {
    let task = obj as Task
    ...
}
```